# Connect DMZ database using SSH tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling

I'm new to ssh tunneling. I'm trying to access a database from developer machine, which is accessible only from my production server.

I am able to open an SSH connection to the production server from the developer machine, but I don't know how to tunnel the remote database port using production server to developer machine.

I have tried the following with no success

```
ssh -L 9999:remote_database:5432 user@production_server
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: The database runs on port 5432 remotely and you want it on 9999 locally? `remote_database` is the name of a server which is reachable over telnet to that port on `production_server`?

Comment: Yes exactly. Database is running on the a machine which is different from prod and dev server. Its accessible only from the prod server on port 5432, so If I wanted to open a connection to it from prod I would use `remote_database:5432`. Now I want to access Database from the dev machine on port 9999 locally by tunneling with SSH.

Comment: use the IP address or remote database in lieu of the name

Comment: Try it!!  Give it a -v flag to make some more noise!  Try to connect to port 9999 on your machine and tell us what happens!

Comment: Still same, port 9999 is open on the dev machine after running ssh tunnel command `ssh -L ...` however when I try to connect to it waits and shows error `connection timed out`.